# How to pass event from outer scroll to inner scroll in a single move

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I have two scrollViews i.e one inside other, 
-OuterScroll
----InnerScroll

Need Outer scrollView to stop automatically and inner starts in a single scroll when outer ScrollView reaches contentOffSet value of greater than 300.

So far..

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (scrollView ==scrollSuperView)
    {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>300) {
            [scrollContentView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<10){
            [scrollContentView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        }

     }
 }
```

By the way scrollSuperView is outerScroll and scrollContentView is inner.
Any help appreciated.

1.scrollSuperView (Outer)
 frame = CGRect(0, 0, 320, 468)
 contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600)

2.scrollContentView (Inner)
 frame = CGRect(0, 300, 320, 468)
 contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600)

So i have above two scrollViews as mentioned outer and inner 
Once outer scrollView reaches content offset of >300 then scrollEvent much be passed to inner ScrollView if user is scrolling by putting finger on inner ScrollView..

Hope its more clear now.

Comment: is this code not working?.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: I am sorry @Vashum its very old post i don't remember what i did at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting outer `scrollView`'s `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` will pass touch events from outer `scrollView` to inner `scrollView`... "*in a single move*"

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == scrollSuperView) {
        //outer scrollView
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 300) {
            //NSLog(@"Outer scrollView ContentOffset has reached 300");
            [scrollSuperView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
            [scrollContentView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
    else if (scrollView == scrollContentView) {
        //inner scrollView
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
            //NSLog(@"Inner scrollView ContentOffset has reached 0");
            [scrollSuperView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
            [scrollContentView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Assumptions:

1. `scrollSuperView` (*Outer*)

   - frame = CGRect(0, 0, 320, 300)
   - contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600)
   - delaysContentTouches = YES
   - scrollEnabled = YES
2. `scrollContentView` (*Inner*)

   - frame = CGRect(0, 400, 320, 200)
   - contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400)
   - delaysContentTouches = YES
   - scrollEnabled = NO

Comment: but i am not sure what should be the default flag for both scrollViews DelaysContentTouches

Comment: @pankajwadhwa : the default `delaysContentTouches` for both `scrollView`s should be `YES`

Comment: @pankajwadhwa : what do you exactly want? it seems that in one single swipe, you want to scroll the outer `scrollView` until the inner `scrollView` comes in frame and then stop the outer scroll and scroll the inner (_all this in one swipe_) so basically you want to pass the scrolling from outer to inner on-the-fly (_in which case, yes, my suggestion won't work_)

Comment: okay let me try to explain it once again, so i am editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 //write your code here
 innerScrollView.scrollEnabled =NO;
 outerScrollView.scrollEnabled =YES;
 //above two lines makes touch(scroll) events given to outer and not inner.
}
```

And your modified method,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (scrollView ==scrollSuperView)
    {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>300) {
            outerScrollView.scrollEnabled =NO;
            innerScrollView.scrollEnabled =YES;
            [outerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 200)];
     }
 }
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (scrollView ==scrollSuperView && decelerate==NO)
    {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>300) {
            outerScrollView.scrollEnabled =NO;
            innerScrollView.scrollEnabled =YES;
            [outerScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 200) animated:YES];
     }
 }
}
```